# How do I isolate spec files when running ng test if the tests to exclude have type errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

We have some unit tests we'd like to run in isolation in our Angular project. The spec file we wanted to test has the right types for each variable, service etc. and no errors showed up in our IDE. We used `fdescribe` to isolate the cases and also tried using `ng test --include` command to isolate them, but type errors are displayed for some of the other spec files in the project. The set of cases we isolated aren't being recognized after the errors are displayed, showing `0 OF 0 SUCCESS` Because our project is large, we'd like to be able to execute specific test cases by including just them and isolating the rest (the cases with errors). I'd like to know if there is a different method to isolate the files which recognizes the isolated set of cases and excludes/ignores the specs with errors in them. We've been facing this issue since Angular 13.

We tried isolating the cases using `fdescribe` and using `ng test --include` But we received `0 OF 0 SUCCESS`. We expected the isolated cases to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try is in `test.ts`, modify this Regex to include the files you would like to include:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

At the moment, it is picking up all files that end in `.spec.ts` but maybe you can modify that Regex to only pick up files that you're concerned with. If you do this, you won't have to play with `fdescribe` or `include`.